# Possible to code a search box that searches for a specific tag in a div and then shows it / hides others?

Tags: jquery, html, css, search

With out making a database backend, is it possible to somehow create a search box on an html / css page, probably with jquery for everything, that say I have four div boxes on the page, and each div box contains certain flavor text or keywords. Is it possible to make a search box that when a keyword is searched for, it then hides the other div boxes that don't contain that keyword, and then shows only those that do.

I am aware and know of .hide / .show /.toggle in jquery, but how would one begin to code a simple search box that would perform that kind of functionality? Anyone have any ideas or general direction?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes but have you tried anything?

Comment: The answer to your question is YES, this is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var key = this.value;
    $(".tosearch").each(function() {
       var $this = $(this);
       $this.toggle($(this).text().indexOf(key) >= 0);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/upsgk/

Note that this performs a case-sensitive search. To ignore case you'll need a couple of calls to [toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase). E.g. http://jsfiddle.net/upsgk/1/

Comment: +1, but, also, this doesn't take captial letters into account.

Comment: OP did not ask for case-insensitive matching, but that can be easily done using a few calls to `toLowerCase()`. Added to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of the key components you'll need:

- `inputtxt.value` (jQuery: `$("input").val()`): returns the value written inside a text `input`.
- `elm.innerHTML` (jQuery: `$("elm").html()`): returns a string containing the contents of an element.
- `str.indexOf(pattern)`: returns the index of the first occurrence of `pattern` in `str`. If `pattern` doesn't exist in`str`, then `.indexOf()` returns -1.

Putting those together, you get something like this: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/SXyUd/). The code is pretty self-explaining, but here's a commented version of the JavaScript part:

```
$("#search").on("keydown keyup keypress change", function() { //when the textbox is changed
    var query = $("#search").val(); //save its content
    $(".box").each(function() { //for each box
        var cur = $(this); //get the current box
        if(cur.html().indexOf(query) == -1) { //see if the current box contains the query
            cur.hide("fast"); //it doesn't; hide it
        }
        else {
            cur.show("fast"); //it does, show it
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I wish I could choose both of your answers and the other poster above, both worked beautifully, thank you to both!

Answer (score 0):

I do not want to do the project for you but here is an idea to start with

```
var query= $('#search').val();
var str = $('#div1').val();

if (str.indexOf(query) >= 0){
   // display box
}
else{
  // hide box
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

1. First listen to the search box prevent defautl using

   $('input[type="submit"]').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();});
2. Program your code to get search box value.
3. Hide all divs `$("div").css("display","none");`
4. Show all divs that have the id `$("#"+valueOfBox").css("display","true");`